# Can I display an android activity with xml in Flutter as a widget?

Tags: android, flutter

It's possible to show an android activity with xml view in Flutter?

I'm using mapbox navigation and want to show map navigation as a widget only,all other view will custom on Flutter.

Anyone have a solutions for me?

Thanks for your support.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to display the android activity with the XML code in the Flutter because both are having different frameworks and displaying engines.

Flutter build the UI using it's own frameworks called widgets and on the other hand the Android uses XML layout to define the UI which is inflated on the runtime and is displaying over the screen.

You must need to create the UI in the Flutter using the framework and widget which you wanted to display over the application.